# How to fix the syntax error "unexpected 'enter' (T_STRING) syntax error, expecting ','"

Tags: php, html, syntax, syntax-error, parse-error

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == ‘POST’)
{
$url = (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : false;
if (!$url) {
echo “Please enter a URL”;
} else {
$source = file_get_contents($url);
$source = urldecode($source);

// Extract video title.
$vTitle_results_1 = explode(‘<title>’, $source);
$vTitle_results_2 = explode(‘</title>’, $vTitle_results_1[1]);

$title = trim(str_replace(‘ – YouTube’, ”, trim($vTitle_results_2[0])));

// Extract video download URL.
$dURL_results_1 = explode(‘url_encoded_fmt_stream_map”: “url=’, $source);
$dURL_results_2 = explode(‘\u0026quality’, $dURL_results_1[1]);

// Force download of video.
$file = str_replace(‘ ‘, ‘_’, strtolower($title)).’.webm’;

header(“Cache-Control: public”);
header(“Content-Description: File Transfer”);
header(“Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file”);
header(“Content-Type: video/webm”);
header(“Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary”);

readfile($dURL_results_2[0]);

exit;
}
}
?>
<form method=”post”>
<label for=”url”>URL:</label>
<input type=”text” name=”url” value=”" id=”url”>
<input type=”submit” name=”submit” value=”Download”>
</form>
```

When I load it I get the following parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'enter' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in ... on line 6

I can't fix this error. Can someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: Simple. Change all your smart/curly quotes to regular ones. `‘’` to `'` and `“` - `”` to `"` yet this line `‘url_encoded_fmt_stream_map”: “url=’, $source` with mix of singles/double will need to be done properly. Not putting an "answer" for this one. Whoever wants a `GO` at this, I wish him/her good luck ;-) - Let's hope you're not going to fall into that proverbial "Can of Worms".

Comment: The quotes on `“Please enter a URL”` are not proper double quotes, but rather some kind of curly quote.  Change them to `"Please enter a URL"` then change all the others too. Be cautious when copy/pasting code from other web sources or editing code in a text editor not meant for code, as this is a common result.

Comment: It is recommended to use a text editor having good support for PHP syntax highlighting. All those improperly quoted strings would show with error highlighting, or at the very least, the wrong color for quoted strings.

Comment: Although not the problem, the `if` and `else` sections really could do with indentation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $url = (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : false;

    if (!$url) {
        echo "Please enter a URL";
    } else {
        $source = file_get_contents($url);
        $source = urldecode($source);

        // Extract video title.
        $vTitle_results_1 = explode('<title>', $source);
        $vTitle_results_2 = explode('</title>', $vTitle_results_1[1]);

        $title = trim(str_replace(' – YouTube', '', trim($vTitle_results_2[0])));

        // Extract video download URL.
        $dURL_results_1 = explode('url_encoded_fmt_stream_map": "url=', $source);
        $dURL_results_2 = explode('\u0026quality', $dURL_results_1[1]);

        // Force download of video.
        $file = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($title)).'.webm';

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: video/webm");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($dURL_results_2[0]);

        exit;
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label for="url">URL:</label> <input type="text" name="url" value=""
        id="url"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```